# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_absolute'

Tags: python, python-2.7, dns, subdomain, dnspython

I have all the resource record sets and resource `types(cname,A,ns,mx)`. I wanted to create a dns file(BIND format) using `easyzone`, `dnspython`, `dns` libraries in python.

But I am getting an error -

**Attribute Error : 'str' object has no attribute 'is_absolute'**

Here is my basic code-

```
    from dns.zone import Zone
    from dns.rdataclass import *
    from dns.rdatatype import *
    zone1 = Zone(origin='example.com.')
    A_add = "example.com."
    print "Adding record of type A:", A_add
    rdataset = zone1.find_rdataset(A_add, rdtype=A, create=True)
    rdata = dns.rdtypes.IN.A.A(IN, A, address="192.168.10.30")
    rdataset.add(rdata, ttl=300)
```

I am getting error on `rdataset = zone1.find_rdataset(A_add, rdtype=A, create=True)`.

How to create a dns file using any of the libraries mentioned above in python and how to resolve the issue?

Comment: What version of DNSPython are you using? It should work fine with A_add being a string (and just convert it to a dns.name.Name)

Comment: easyzone ==1.2.2
dnspython == 1.12.0
and can you please add a line to convert **A_add to dns.name.Name** because even after that the problem persist !

Comment: I did that, it works but now I am getting 
**AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CNAME'** and **AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'A'** Errors in the lines **rdata = dns.rdtypes.ANY.CNAME.CNAME(IN, CNAME, target)** and **rdata = dns.rdtypes.IN.A.A(IN, A, address="192.168.10.30")**. I am importing it correctly although !